# Trying to save different values in 2 arrays using one FOR loop but the first array is been attributed the value of the second input

Tags: c++, arrays

I am testing the ability to use functions to input values in 2 arrays and also to perform addition of the values. I wish to input the different values in the 2 arrays using a function `inputArray(A1, A2, size)` using a For loop.
I also used a function `sumArray(A1, A2, size)` to perform the addition of the 2 values in the arrays.

But the issue is with the input function as when i am running the program to input different values in the 2 arrays,  the first array is also been attributed the value of the second array.

```
void inputArray(int Array1[], int Array2[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Array 1:"<<endl;

        cin>>Array1[i];

        cout<<" Array 2: "<<endl;

        cin>>Array2[i];
        cout<<endl;

        //test
        cout<<"\n\t A1[0]= "<<Array1[0]<<endl;
        cout<<"\n\t A2[0]="<<Array2[0]<<endl;
    }
}
```

I tried to use 2 different functions to input the values and this worked.But then again when i used a FOR loop for the Addition function `sum = sumArray(A1, A2, size)`, both arrays `A1` and `A2` were being attributed the value of the second array.

```
int sumArray(int Array1[], int Array2[], int n)
{
    int sum= 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum+= ( Array1[i] + Array2[i] );
        cout<<"The total sum so far for values till position "<<i<<" is "<<sum<<endl;  
    }

    //to monitor if the program is performing well with the addition

    //test
    cout<<"\n\t A1[0]= "<<Array1[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t A2[1]="<<Array2[2]<<endl;

    return sum;
}
```

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void inputArray(int Array1[], int Array2[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Array 1:"<<endl;

        cin>>Array1[i];

        cout<<" Array 2: "<<endl;

        cin>>Array2[i];
        cout<<endl;

        //test
        cout<<"\n\t A1[0]= "<<Array1[0]<<endl;
        cout<<"\n\t A2[0]="<<Array2[0]<<endl;
    }
}

//To sum all the values in the 2 arrays//not asked in the question

int sumArray(int Array1[], int Array2[], int n)

{
    int sum= 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum+= ( Array1[i] + Array2[i] );
        cout<<"The total sum so far for values till position "<<i<<" is "<<sum<<endl;  
    }
    //to monitor if the program is performing well with the addition


    //test
    cout<<"\n\t A1[0]= "<<Array1[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t A2[1]="<<Array2[2]<<endl;

    return sum;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int size;

    int A1[size];
    int A2[size];

    size= 3;

    cout<<"Input "<<size<<" values in the first  and second array: "<<endl;

    inputArray( A1, A2, size);  //do not write square bracket when calling a function

    int sum = sumArray(A1, A2, size);
    cout<<"The sum of the total values is : "<<sum<<endl;


    //test
    cout<<"\n\t A1[0]= "<<A1[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\t A2[1]="<<A2[2]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What size do you expect your arrays to have after `int size;

    int A1[size];
    int A2[size];` ? Do you expect the subsequently executed line `size= 3;` to have any influence on that?

Comment: Do you not get any compiler warnings with that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you use a non-initialised variable for the size of the two arrays.

```
int size;
int A1[size];
int A2[size];
```

This is in C++ wrong in more than one way.
You need to define C-like arrays with a constant size.
Safer would be to use C++ containers, e.g. `std::vector` for anything without predictable size.

Even in C, where VLAs are possible, creating them like you did and LATER reading in a new value for `size` will not change anything, especially not the size of the arrays.

Also, but that is already inside undefined behaviour and purely speculative,
if the compiler understands that as `A1` and `A2`of size 0, then the start of both arrays is the same and writing to one writes also to the other - AND be totally forbidden because it will access beyond any arrays size.

To demonstrate that, try

```
int A1[5];
int A2[5];
```